# The font properties looks similar but looks and feel is different in two pdf documents

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I have a PDF template document given by my client as a reference. My application has to create it. When i compared the PDF generated by my application and the template given by the client i could see the look and feel are slightly different.I opened it in Adobe acrobat pro dc, i could still see the font properties are same. Please see the link below to see the PDFs header i created which has the above mentioned issue.

Please see the image:

[image]

I have the font properties defined in xml as below.This will be unmarshalled later.

```
<font name="Arial Narrow" id="blackBold" fsize="12" type="bold" rgb="0,0,0"/>
```

I have the different font type defined in a map like below,

```
fontAndAlignmentMap.put("bold", 1);
//Internally this will be resolved to-->com.itextpdf.text.Font.BOLD = 1;
```

The itext Font will be created from an unmarshalled xml font object as below:

```
FontFactory.registerDirectories();
com.itextpdf.text.Font itextFont = 
    FontFactory.getFont(sbcFont.getName(), sbcFont.getFsize(), fontAndAlignmentMap.get(sbcFont.getType()), new BaseColor(r,g,b));
```

The 10 page pdf document have different fonts and formatting.The Statically defined fonts are unmarshalled and loaded into the itextFontMap as shown below.

```
itextFontMap.put(sbcFont.getId(), itextFont);
```

sbcFont.getId() are "blackBold","blackRegular" etc.Depends on the use the appropriate font will be pulled from this map.

```
Phrase pSbc = new Phrase("Summary of Benefits and Coverage:", 
    SBCMappingSingletonBuilder.itextFontMap.get("blackBold"));`  
Phrase pSbcDesc = new Phrase(
    " What this Plan Covers & What You Pay For Covered Services", 
    SBCMappingSingletonBuilder.itextFontMap.get("blackRegular"));
```

When i printed the family name of the com.itextpdf.text.Font object.

```
blackBold.getFamilyname() :Arial Narrow 
blackRegular.getFamilyname() :Arial Narrow
```

This is what printed from the code.

```
sbcFont.getName() :Arial Narrow Bold
sbcFont.getName() :Arial Narrow
```

`Phrase`s added to a `PdfPCell`; `PdfPCell` added to `PdfPTable` and then to the `document`.
Can any one please throw some light here.I am using java 1.6 and itextpdf-5.3.4

The sample template which i am referring please click
  [here](http://docdro.id/0t8Lbr1)

The one i am tring to create similar to the template,please click
  [here](http://docdro.id/Jtigj8k)

I opened the pdf in Adobe Acrobat Pro.The bold font look like narrow even though the font properties are showing as bold in Adobe Acrobat Pro.But when i opened the pdf in a browser,it looks good.

Comment: I edited the question because it was very hard to read, and I thought that was due to the formatting. Now that the question is properly formatted, it is still hard to read. We would need to see the PDFs, but also: what is `itextFontMap` and why would that map understand `"blackBold"` and `"blackRegular"`? What does `sbcFont.getName()` return, and are you sure that `itextFont` isn't just Helvetica because `sbcFont.getName()` can't be recognized as a registered font? What is this `fontAndAlignmentMap` about? It's very strange that you map a style to an integer. This question is unanswerable.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse i have updated the code and provided the link to the pdf files.Thanks.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie thanks for editing my question and framing it in a better shape.I have provided the details including the pdf files.please review it.Thanks

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse do you see any issues with the PDFs i have provided?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie do you see the issue when you compared the PDFs?am i missing something while creating the PDFs?

Comment: @sush I have not looked at your PDF files. In fact, after I added my comment where I asked you to add files and code, I never intended to look at the question any further. I only asked it to help out others who might come along, so they would have it easier to help you. Since you have added code and provided sample files, my comment is no longer relevant and I have deleted it.

Comment: @Sush You're not embedding any of your fonts, which tells me that you didn't bother to read any of the iText documentation on fonts. You expect an answer from the person who spent a lot of time on writing that documentation. That expectation is wrong: read the documentation.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie -- "You're not embedding any of your font".This is all what i need.rest is my job.Thanks for the help.At the moment this is a low priority one for me.Will update the comments soon.

Comment: For now FontFactory.defaultEmbedding = true; resolved my issue.@BrunoLowagie thanks again for the right pointer.